# Add 'last' class to records from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I'm using a parametized query to get records that will display as a grid of products on a page. My design has 4 products listed in each row, but i'd like to apply a class to every 4th item, so that I can clear any margins/padding.

Here is my current code;

```
<%
        Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
        conn.Open Application("database")
        Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.command")
        With cmd
                .ActiveConnection = conn
                .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                .CommandText = "prc_getCollection"
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@LabelID", adInteger, adParamInput,, 5)
                Set rsCollection = .Execute
        End With
%>

<% While Not rsCollection.EOF %>
<li>Product Name</li>

<%
                rsCollection.MoveNext
        Wend
        rsCollection.Close()
        Set rsCollection = Nothing
%>
```

If anyone knows how I can apply a "last" class to every 4th

item, that would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a long time since I have done any classic asp so the syntax may be slightly off. The usual approach is to increment a counter and use the modulus operator to determine if you are on a row number that is an exact multiple of 4.

```
<% 
Dim counter
counter = 0

While Not rsCollection.EOF 
counter = counter + 1

if (counter mod 4 =0) Then
Response.Write "<li class='last'>Product Name</li>"
Else
Response.Write "<li>Product Name</li>"
End If
%>
```